# Audit of bash (writing to logfile)

Tags: bash, pipe, exec, audit, tee

I would like to write the content of my **bash** shell into a logfile. The logfile should contain **STDIN**, **STDOUT** and **STDERR**.

The most obvious solution to achieve this is to use the `script`-executable:

```
script --flush audit.log
```

But there are two disadvantages:

1. The logfile contains ugly characters such as: **^M**
2. a new process is created

I am looking for a solution without these disadvantages.
And I would like to know where **^M** comes from and what it means.

I have not found **^M**
in  output of `infocmp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start a shell, which writes everything to audit.log you can do this:

```
bash -i 2>&1 | tee "audit.log"
```

With this the audit.log does not contain any more **^M**.

`2>&1` redirects **STDERR** to **STDOUT**, which is then piped to tee. Tee writes the text,
which it receives from the pipe to both **STDOUT** and file audit.log.

To avoid that a new process is started you can use the bash built-in command `exec`:

```
exec > >(tee  "audit.log" )                                                                                                                               
exec 2>&1
```

exec allows to redirect **STDOUT** of current process to a file. `>)` pipes to tee, which then writes to **STDOUT** and `audit.log`.

Comment: Question asks about stdin also, so you might need another `tee` on the input (to a different log file).